# What is the best way to update an object in a usestate and see the change immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx, use-state

```
const TestScreen = (props) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([ 
            { "id": "0", "user": "Lisa","amount": 1 },
        ]);

        return(
            <View style={{
                            flex:1, 
                            alignItems:'center',
                            justifyContent:'center'
                        }}>
            <Text>amount : {data[0].amount}</Text>
            <Text>User : {data[0].user}</Text>
            <Button title="update" onPress={()=>setData(??????)}></Button>
          </View>
           
        )
    }
  
  export default TestScreen;
```

what is the best way to add an amount number on the user Lisa? i can do
// setData([{ "id": "0", "user": "Lisa","amount": data[0].amount + 1}])
but what i have 5 users or 20?

even with a returning function nothing gets updated exept console logged witch show me the actual value

```
   let countAddFunc =(getArr)=>{
          let arr = getArr
          arr[0].amount++
          console.log(arr[0].amount);
          return(
            arr
          )
        }

<Button title="update" onPress={()=>setData(countAddFunc(data))}></Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the key concepts in React is [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). This can be tricky sometimes, especially when dealing with nested data like in your example (a `number` as a property of an object inside an array).

Below, I refactored your code and added comments to help explain. By creating a function to update the state, and passing that function to each child component's props, the child component will be able to update the state by calling the function.

```js
const {useState} = React;

// component dedicated to displaying each item in the array
const Item = (props) => (
  <div style={{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}>
    <div>Amount: {props.item.amount}</div>
    <div>User: {props.item.user}</div>
    <button onClick={() => {
      props.updateAmount(props.item.user);
    }}>Increment</button>
  </div>
);

const ItemList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: '0',
      user: 'Lisa',
      amount: 1,
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      user: 'Walter',
      amount: 3,
    },
  ]);

  const updateAmount = (user, changeAmount = 1) => {
    // find the index of the item we want
    const index = data.findIndex(item => item.user === user);

    // return early (do nothing) if it doesn't exist
    if (index === -1) return;

    const item = data[index];

    // don't modify state directly (item is still the same object in the state array)
    const updatedItem = {
      ...item,
      amount: item.amount + changeAmount,
    };

    // again, don't modify state directly: create new array
    const updatedArray = [...data];

    // insert updated item at the appropriate index
    updatedArray[index] = updatedItem;

    setData(updatedArray);
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <Item item={item} updateAmount={updateAmount} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<ItemList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try like this once, pass second param as user id you want to update

```html
<Button title="update" onPress={()=>setData(countAddFunc(data, 0))}></Button>
```

```html
let countAddFunc =(getArr, id)=>{
          const arrCopy = [...getArr]
          const user = arrCopy.find(u => u.id === id )
          if (user) {
             user.amount++
          }
          return arrCopy
        }
```

actually you are modifying the state directly, and we can not update state directly and getArr is just a refrence to the data in state, so, we created a copy of array, and modified copied array, and then we set this new array into the state, about the code throwing undefined error, add a check, if (user) user.amount++ and make sure id you send onPress={()=>setData(countAddFunc(data, 0))} actually exist

Comment: I tried your code and i get
`undefined is not an object(evaluating 'user.amount')`

Comment: When adding  [...getArr] into the countAddFunc() get's the job done... why is that?

Comment: actually you were modifying the state directly, and we can not update state directly, getArr is just a refrence to the data in state, so, we created a copy of array, and modified copied array, and then we set this new array into the state, about the code throwing undefined error, add a check, if (user) user.amount++ and make sure id you send onPress={()=>setData(countAddFunc(data, 0))} actually exist

Answer (score 0):

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately. setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

Read the official documentation for more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Also, alternatively you can use useRef or useEffect with dependency array if you want the callback to immediately fire and do the changes.

Comment: i tried adding the useEffect it dosen't log out anything

`useEffect(() => {
          console.log("Logged out");
 },[data]);`

Comment: But when adding [...getArr] get's the job done & prints out in useEffect "Logged out" Why is that? what difference does if make adding [...getArr] then just getArr

        `let countAddFunc =(getArr)=>{
          let arr = [...getArr]
          arr[0].amount++
          setData(arr)
        }`